# Using `self = [self init]` to wrap other `init message`

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Is it acceptable/safe in Objective-C/Cocoa to wrapping the `init` method as follows:

```
-(id)init {
    if ((self=[super init])) {
         self.bar = [[Bar alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithFoo:(Foo *)f {
    if ((self=[self init])) {
         self.foo = f;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Note the `[self init]` in `initWithFoo`.**

*perhaps this is a simple yes answer... seem obvious, but not standard?*

Comment: It's acceptable. My only comment is about second method. It's alvays better to use something like this: -(id)initWithFoo:(Foo)newFoo { ....  self.foo = newFoo .... }

Comment: sorry, was quickly illustrating the question... will correct the semantics

Comment: I’d say it’s uncommon: your `initWithFoo:` is the initializer that does the most. But it does so _indirectly_ by calling another initializer, that does something else. Common (and _good!_) practice is to have _one_ designated initializer. The most specific one, the one all other initializers call with default arguments. And that would be number two, as it initializes two ivars: `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: true. i actually have `init` and `initWithJSON:`.

Comment: perhaps there should be just `init:` and `parseJSON` if it is uncommon? `initWithJSON` calls `parseJSON` in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's certainly acceptable and safe.  I'm not certain if it's standard practice, but I don't think it's bad practice.

**Note:** This is not *overloading*.  Overloading refers to a very specific thing in C-like languages (particularly C++) where you have multiple functions with the same name, distinguished only by their numbers and/or types of parameters.  A better term for this would probably be something like *forwarding* or *wrapping*.

Comment: It's definitely standard practice. it's the whole point of _designated initializer_. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party but I thought I'd add my two cents.

If you provide both an init (which you definitely will do) and an initWithBlah then you'd be best doing something like this...

```
- (id)initWithValue:(int)value
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.value = value;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    int defaultValue = 10;

    return [self initWithValue:defaultValue];
}
```